# Kendo UI Grid multiple records insert

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In my MVC4 project with kendo UI grid wrong methods are calling and when a right method is fired then the record is inserted twice when i add a new record i can see worker thread running twice on the same insert method and sometimes update perform create operation please some one help  me out

Comment: This seems pretty odd (never faced), are you sure you are calling/spelling appropriate methods (CRUD)?

Comment: As result of the `create` you should an `id` different than the default value (typically `null`). Is your method returning it? Otherwise Kendo UI thinks that you did not update it and might send it back with a further request since it is kept marked as `dirty`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar situation but in our case the field with the id has a different name so our model has a redefinition of the id field ..model: { id: someOtherfield, ...

The only thing that worked for us was to do a `dataSource.read()` as part of `requestEnd if  e.type == 'create'`